# Not able to set value to text box in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have below code where i am calling yahoo api servicecall and putting those value in text box. But i am not able to put fetched value in textbox. Below is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<form name="converter">
<table border="0">
<tr>
<td><p class= "text_color">INR:</p> </td><td><input type="text" name="euro" onChange="euroConverter()" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><p class= "text_color">US Dollar: </p></td><td><input type="text" name="dollar" onChange="dollarConverter()" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="4" align="center"><input type="button" value="Convert!" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<script language="JavaScript">
  function getRate(from, to) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('src', "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20rate%2Cname%20from%20csv%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.finance.yahoo.com%2Fd%2Fquotes%3Fs%3D"+from+to+"%253DX%26f%3Dl1n'%20and%20columns%3D'rate%2Cname'&format=json&callback=parseExchangeRate");
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }

  function parseExchangeRate(data) {
    var name = data.query.results.row.name;
    var rate = parseFloat(data.query.results.row.rate, 10);
  }

function euroConverter(){
document.getElementsByName('dollar').value = document.getElementsByName('euro').value * getRate("INR", "USD");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

In above code i wont get any error but i am not able to put fetched value in textbox.I know i am missing some basic thing.Any help on this.

Comment: `* getRate` your getRate function doesn't, and can NOT under any circumstances, return a value

Comment: also, your `parseExchangeRate` callback for the JSONP in `getRate` extracts `name` and `rate` into local variables, which are immediately discarded

Comment: @Jaromanda X yes, i can only see alert of values inside getRate function. So how could i put this values to text box?

Comment: the rate is *available* inside your `parseExchangeRate` callback function

Answer (score 0):

here's an extremely simple (and simplistic) rewrite of two of your functions

```
function parseExchangeRate(data) {
    var name = data.query.results.row.name;
    var rate = parseFloat(data.query.results.row.rate, 10);
    document.getElementsByName('dollar').value = document.getElementsByName('euro').value * rate;
}

function euroConverter() {
    getRate("INR", "USD");
}
```

This should now work, with no change to `getRate` required

I say it's simplistic, because you should be able to "cache" the result and not have to call for the exchange rate on every change, but you should get the idea of how to deal with such asynchronous JSONP data with this minimal change

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to return a single element, it will return an array with one element.

```
document.getElementsByName('dollar')
```

You can however grab the first element

```
var dollarTextbox = document.getElementsByName('dollar')[0];
```

Now that you have the textbox you can put the value you want on it

```
dollarTextbox.value = '0';
```

The Yahoo api is going to call your function `parseExchangeRate` it is inside this function that you need to assign the value

```
function parseExchangeRate(data) {
  var name = data.query.results.row.name;
  var rate = parseFloat(data.query.results.row.rate, 10);

  var dollarTextbox = document.getElementsByName('dollar')[0];
  var euroTextbox = document.getElementsByName('euro')[0];

  dollarTextbox.value = euroTextbox.value * rate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax calls to fetch the date from the yahoo servers.

```js
    function getRate(from, to, callback) {

      var url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20rate%2Cname%20from%20csv%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.finance.yahoo.com%2Fd%2Fquotes%3Fs%3D" + from + to + "%253DX%26f%3Dl1n'%20and%20columns%3D'rate%2Cname'&format=json"
      callAjax(url, callback);
    }

    function parseExchangeRate(data) {
      var name = data.query.results.row.name;
      var rate = parseFloat(data.query.results.row.rate, 10);
    }

    function callAjax(url, callback) {
      var xmlhttp;
      // compatible with IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
          callback(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
      }
      xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
      xmlhttp.send();
    }

    function euroConverter() {
      getRate("INR", "USD", function(data) {
        var dataObj = JSON.parse(data);
        var name = dataObj.query.results.row.name;
        var rate = parseFloat(dataObj.query.results.row.rate, 10);
        document.getElementsByName('dollar')[0].value = document.getElementsByName('euro')[0].value * rate;
      });
    }

    function dollarConverter() {
      getRate("USD", "INR", function(data) {
        var dataObj = JSON.parse(data);
        var name = dataObj.query.results.row.name;
        var rate = parseFloat(dataObj.query.results.row.rate, 10);
        document.getElementsByName('euro')[0].value = document.getElementsByName('dollar')[0].value * rate;
      });
    }
```

```html
 <p id="demo"></p>
  <form name="converter">
    <table border="0">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p class="text_color">INR:</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="euro" onChange="euroConverter()" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p class="text_color">US Dollar: </p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="dollar" onChange="dollarConverter()" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4" align="center">
          <input type="button" value="Convert!" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
```